# How to set ForeignKey in the model depending on a slug?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a registration form for an event. Since this registration form displays as a modal when clicking the 'Register' button on the event page, I know what event it is that the user want to register to. But Django doesn't, since I don't know how to implement this in code.

I have two models: `Participant` and `Event`. Each instance of `Participant` refers to an `Event` instance by means of `ForeignKey`. How do I set that `ForeignKey` depending on the slug of the event page?

This is my code example:

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    #<...>
    slug = models.SlugField()

class Participant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField()
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

forms.py:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm

from .models import Participant

class ParticipantForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Participant
        fields =  ['name', 'email']
```

views.py:

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.views import generic

from .models import *
from .forms import *

class RegistrationView(generic.FormView):

    template_name = 'me/registration.html'
    form_class = ParticipantForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['event'] = Event.objects.get(slug=self.args[0])
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return HttpResponse(render_to_string('me/registration-complete.html', {'event': Event.objects.get(slug=self.args[0])}))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to set it in `form_valid`. In this circumstance `get_context_data` wouldn't have been called, so you need to get the event again; you might want to extract that into a separate method.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.event = Event.objects.get(reference_name=self.args[0])
    form.save()
    return ...
```